# CNN - Confusion Matrix wrong display

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, conv-neural-network, confusion-matrix

I have trained a model for handwritten digits multiclass classification using CNN in Keras. I am trying to evaluate the model with the same training images to get an estimate of the accuracy of the algorithm; however, when I evaluate the CNN confusion matrix, it gives a one column only of the form:

```
[[4132    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [4684    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [4177    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [4351    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [4072    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [3795    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [4137    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [4401    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [4063    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [4188    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]]
```

I guess the algorithm is giving the correct result since those are the total numbers of each digit in the database; however, the confusion matrix should give something like this:

```
[[4132    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0 4684    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0 4177    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0 4351    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0 4072    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0 3795    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0 4137    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 4401    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 4063    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 4188]]
```

[The code is in this link](https://github.com/elopezfune/Number_Digit_CNN)

[The data can be taken from the "train.csv" file in this Kaggle project.](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/data)

I would like to ask you guys what am I doing wrong in the code, such that I obtain this weird result.

Comment: Without looking at the code; what gives you the impression that the algorithm is giving the correct result? If your network misclassifies everything as class 0, the confusion matrix you get is completely valid.

Comment: Yes but the confusion matrix for a 100% well classified problem should be diagonal. If you check the code, the accuracy is 9.84 % which is really bad, that's why I would like to know if the code is well written, in order to get the correct diagonal matrix and the correct accuracy estimation.

Comment: @user115376 if an answer solves your question, please mark it as accepted by clicking on a gray tick below the answer score

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked your code and I have a solution to your problem. The calculation of the Confusion Matrix works as well as possible. The problem is that your network is not learning at all and it classifies all data to 0. You can verify this by setting the verbose argument to 1 in the fit function and then you can observe an accuracy of about 10%, which is equivalent to random guessing.

```
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_train, Y_train), verbose=1)
```

It's because you don't normalize your data. All you have to do is to divide your dataset by 255 so that the number values are in the range [0; 1] and then everything is working properly and your network is learning.

```
X_train = X.reshape((-1, 28, 28, 1))
X_train = X_train / 255.0
Y_train = to_categorical(Y)
```

The same thing you should do with your test set.

Comment: To be specific, the accuracy of 9.84% is because when you classify everything as calss 0, you only get class 0 correct. Which is `4132 / 42000 = 0.0984`. :)

Comment: I tried normalizing the training subsample and still doesn't work...

Comment: @user115376 I have just checked it once again. Normalization helps, I have done a fork of your repository and made a pull request with an updated version of the notebook which actually works fine. Please check it.

Comment: Yes, now I saw it and ran it and it works perfectly. I don't know what I was doing wrong besides the normalization. I will deepend more into the code. Thanks again.